# When repeating image in image view its display small small slot in iOS

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview

In my application want to repeat image in imageview but when i repeat image small small slot display  how to resolved??
I tried below code :

```
 self.bgimg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"pattern-dots"]];
```

Comment: Can you add an image of current output and desired output ?

Comment: @Stela please display image.

Comment: Please Check my uploaded image .. small square square image u can see.. and  u can see i outlined square box with red border also so u can  easily understand

Comment: UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern-dots"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.5 topCapHeight:0];

  [_scro setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage]];

Comment: self.bgimg.clipToBounds = YES;

Comment: @Stela, edit your code and add my code, try once

Comment: @Stela, Add two lines also..

[self.bgimg. setOpaque:NO];
[[self.bgimg. layer] setOpaque:NO];

Comment: yes mehul  i tried your code also .. but its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88468/discussion-between-mehul-and-stela).

Comment: @Stela, U got your Solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Because your image size is smaller than the view size.
So, you provide enough larger image than self.view size.

You can try to check by bellow code fragment.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"pattern-dots"];//@"oval"
if (self.view.frame.size.width<=image.size.width) {
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
}else{
    NSLog(@"You image is too small to fit.");
}

NSLog(@"view Size:%@",NSStringFromCGSize(self.view.frame.size));
NSLog(@"imsge Size:%@",NSStringFromCGSize(image.size));
```

Comment: it gives me  same result as like my uploaded image

Comment: i have edited my answer. please send me the log output

Comment: view Size:{320, 568}
 imsge Size:{10, 10}

Comment: please look the "pattern-dots" {width,height} == {10,10}. But your view size is Size:{320, 568}. So to solve the repeating issue. You should provide  "pattern-dots" image size: {320, 568}